# about using AVMutableComposition to composite clips,

Tags: objective-c, ios, video-processing

I'm using AVMutableComposition to composite(concatenate) video clips, the code is from Apple Sample project AVEditDemo, there are three clips:
A.mov  7.4MB
B.mov  24MB
C.mov  10.9MB

after exporting, the result video is 106.4MB, is this normal? is there any way to compress it?

Answer (score 1):

you can try exporting with a different preset/quality.